# Having a confirmation screen before deleting a database value

Tags: php, javascript, sql

I'm having a problem with making a confirmation screen.

I want to pop up a confirmation screen before deleting the value in my database. The pop up screen is being called by clicking on a icon/button. However, when I press "OK" the value is being deleted, but also when I press "Cancel".

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmation() {
    var answer = confirm("Weet u zeker dat u deze activiteit wilt verwijderen?")
    if (answer){
        alert("De activiteit wordt nu verwijderd.")
        window.location = "roosters_verwijderen.php";
    }
    else{
        alert("De activiteit is niet verwijderd.")

    }
}
</script>
```

The button:

```
<a href="roosters_verwijderen.php?activiteitID='. $row['activiteitID'] .'" onclick="confirmation()" value=""><IMG src="iconen/kruis.png" border="0"></a>
```

Does anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: Just to let you know there are quite a few security concerns.

Answer (score 7):

Change the "onclick" to `confirmation(); return false`

That will prevent the browser from carrying out the default action of your `<a>` tag. Now, another problem you're going to have is that the "id" value coded into the `<a>` tag isn't there in your function. You could pass it in as a parameter I guess.

Comment: This is not working perfectly yet. Now it won't delete the value in the database anymore when I press "OK". Strange enough it does call on roosters_verwijderen.php, it doesnt delete the value.

Comment: I've upvoted Pointy's answer because I mostly agree with it, but also, don't forget to use semicolons after your operations. If you don't use semicolons you might get errors or your code might run into unexpected waters.